# How to do a dynamic query based on an NSArray of data with parse.com on iOS

Tags: ios, nsarray, parse-platform

I need to query a large number of friends messages for a user in Parse.

I have a Friend_Relation object with two users, a friend and a current user.

Each user has many Message objects (i am concerned only with the most current). The relation loos like this:
     [message setObject:currentUser forKey:@"userMessage"];

The user object has an attribute for the most current message objectId.

**How do I get all of a user's friends and their messages?**

I was thinking if I could query all of a user's friends that is easy.  If I could then create an NSArray of the objectIds that I get from a users friends, I could another single query to get back all of those user's messages.  How could I create this type of query on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is definitely to use the contained in method like so:

```
NSArray *names = [self.user objectForKey:@"friends"];
        [query whereKey:@"userMessaga" containedIn:names];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use an inner query to achieve this:

```
PFQuery *getAllFriendsInnerQuery = [[currentUser relationForKey:@"friend"] query];
PFQuery *messageQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
[messageQuery whereKey:@"userMessage" matchesQuery:getAllFriendsInnerQuery];
[messageQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
    // Here the parameter array contains all the messages from current user's friends
}];
```